# confirmation link in Rails test environment renders: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /users/confirmation on this server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot, minitest

I have a `User` class that uses `devise :confirmable`, which, when a user is created, triggers an email to be sent containing a confirmation link. This works perfectly in `development` and `production`, but fails in the `test` environment (Minitest / Capybara). Specifically, clicking the confirmation link results in `**Forbidden** You don't have permission to access /users/confirmation on this server`.

Screenshot:

[**Forbidden** You don't have permission to access /users/confirmation on this server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5FPB.png)

Oddly, when I create the user from `rails console`, just as I do in the integration test, it works. So, why does it fail in the `test` environment?

Test:

```
u = FactoryBot.create(:user)
email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
plain_part = email.multipart? ? (email.text_part ? email.text_part.body.decoded : nil) : email.body.decoded
confirmation_link = plain_part[/<a href="(http:\/\/.*)">Confirm my account<\/a>/,1]
puts "--- #{confirmation_link} ---" # visual check of extracted URL
visit confirmation_link # Forbidden You don't have permission...
save_and_open_screenshot # saves to tmp/capybara/capybara-*.png
```

And at the console:

```
require 'factory_bot'
# factory creation code omitted from here
u = FactoryBot.create(:user)
# produces and renders link
```

Such confirmation links look like this in all environments except `test`:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=TxYdRmVzcuPE7PAx7yJh
```

...and in `test` they look like this:

```
http://localhost/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=NqyaVL5EKEnz46zMzDQs
```

(No port specified in `test`.)

I am using `Rails 5.2.0` with Capybara driver `selenium_chrome_headless` in these *integration* tests.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using, and which driver are you using with Capybara? Also - the confirmation link is going to port 3000 -- Are you actually running your test server on port 3000? Usually that's the dev server

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. You had the right idea... it was to do with ports! By adding `Capybara.server_port = '3000'` to `test/test_helper.rb`, and by modifying (in the integration test) the URL generated by the email, via `confirmation_link.gsub!(/localhost/,"localhost:#{Capybara.server_port}")`, it worked immediately. The latter doesn't feel like a longterm solution, as it seems brittle to monkey patch, but it does confirm the problem. Ideally, the generated URL would use the provided port number. Perhaps you can advise in this regard? Either way, please provide an answer, and I'll accept it!

Comment: ...Or perhaps there is a different and better way of doing this... like somehow getting the generated URL to include the current port number (because I see that it changes with each test run... e.g. `Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:60770`, `Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:60127`, `Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:58623`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the URL being generated in the email isn't pointing back to the Capybara server.  There are a few ways to fix this. The two simplest solutions would be

1. Fix the port Capybara runs its test server on and set the email generation parameters

   ```
   Capybara.server_port = 1111 # any fixed port number

   # in config/environments/test.rb
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost', port: '1111'} # match whatever server host and port Capybara is running on
   ```
2. Continue allowing Capybara to run on a random port, configure the url generation not to include a port, and set Capybara to always include the server port when no other port is explicitly specified

   ```
   Capybara.always_include_port = true

   # in config/environments/test.rb
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost'} # match the host Capybara is running the test server on
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was derailed from this task until now. I tried option 1 above, but it did not work; also, did you not mean to use quotes (`Capybara.server_port = '1111' `)? I tried with and without quotes, to no avail. Option 2 did work - so thank you for that. But any idea why option 1 did not work? And: What problem is there with setting `Capybara.server_port = '3000'` (i.e. using the same port as dev)... what issues/symptoms might arise?

Comment: @user664833 No idea why Option 1 didn't work for you -- check what urls are being generated in the email and see if they're correct.  As for port 3000 -- if you set Capybara to run the tests on port 3000 then you can't continue to develop on your dev instance while tests are running.

Comment: I finally got Option 1 to work. I ended up finding an old line from previous debugging (prior to getting your help), and that old line simply got lost in the shuffle and happened to get in the way here. Anyway, now that I got Option 1 working, I can confirm that it does not matter whether `server_port` has quotes or not. It can be written as `Capybara.server_port = '1111'` or `Capybara.server_port = 1111`.